# Using ADB on Android phone

Tags: android, adb

I am using adb on Android phone.

I did./adb  shell

and I can see the folders inside the phone

I type  cd /sdcard

but it said permission denied.

I can't use su or sudo to make myself root.

How can I make myself as root?

Comment: same thing,  permission denied.

Answer (score 0):

You should root your android phone and then you can use su command in adb.

There is some useful information in this link [www.androidcentral.com/root](http://www.androidcentral.com/root)